# How to see qt ide promoted ui elements in designer window?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it currently possible to make Qt ide generate visuals for promoted ui elements in designer widget/window where it gets promoted to?

Comment: Did you consider about [http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html)?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Promotion just creates a simple placeholder.